# Create helm chart for a job

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am creating a helm chart for the job I want to run in our k8 cluster. When you execute `helm create` it creates templates that I do not need.

```
$ helm create new-job               
Creating new-job

$ tree new-job/
new-job/
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── hpa.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── service.yaml
│   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   └── tests
│       └── test-connection.yaml
└── values.yaml

3 directories, 10 files
```

Is there a way to only create a template containing only job.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Helm has the option to use a custom "starter":

```
helm create --starter /path/to/starter/chart my-chart
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magical about `helm create`.  Just so long as the chart has a [`Chart.yaml` file](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file) and a `templates` subdirectory, Helm can install it.  You can `mkdir` an empty directory and create the `Chart.yaml` file from scratch using your favorite text editor, if you'd prefer.

```yaml
# Chart.yaml, with only the required fields
apiVersion: v2
name: my-chart
version: '0.0.1'
```

```sh
mkdir my-chart; cd my-chart
$EDITOR Chart.yaml
mkdir templates
$EDITOR templates/job.yaml
helm install --generate-name .
```

You can also go the other direction; start from the `helm create` template and delete all of the parts you don't need.  Of note, there are a couple of generically helpful things in `_helpers.tpl` you might want to retain.  (Keeping the ServiceAccount turns out to be useful in a couple of situations, and if you use Istio, it also likes you to have a Service even if you don't accept inbound connections.)